# Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and want to run a code in Python.
Code that I have written is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    results = re.search('ipAddress=([^&]*])', line)
    if len(results.group(1)) != 0:
        print results.group(1)
```

Requirement is finding IP address in a string.String will be something like this

> blah....ipAddress=173.110.208.118&deviceId
>
> Output: 173.110.208.118

Please let me know what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've got one `]` too many there. Try

```
results = re.search('ipAddress=([^&]*)', line)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your input looks like [URL query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Don't parse it by regexp, consider to use [urlparse.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) or [urlparse.parse_qsl](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) (for Python version less than 2.6 use [cgi.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs) or [cgi.parse_qsl](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qsl) respectively). Those functions hide many low level details, for example handling of [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) characters.

Example code for `urlparse.parse_qs`:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> query = parse_qs("ipAddress=173.110.208.118&deviceId=Some%20Id")
>>> query["ipAddress"]
['173.110.208.118']
>>> query["deviceId"]
['Some Id']
```

In [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module you can also find functions for extracting query string from a full URL.

Comment: I wrote python code first time.I think regex is working fine me.Any specific reason for not using regex?

Comment: For very simple tasks like extracting IPs from bunch of a lines it's OK to use regexp. But in this case you can also use one line AWK code like this: `awk '/ipAddress=/ {print $2}' FS='ipAddress=|&' < lines.txt`. If you learn Python it's important to know about most frequently used modules in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

If you're paranoid about regex being too greedy you can use this one to explicitly match the contents like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

```
>import re
>s = "blah...ipAddress=173.110.208.118&deviceid"
>results = re.search('ipAddress=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)',s)
>results.groups()

('173.110.208.118',)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Any specific reason for not using regex?*

No, there's no need of a more complicated tool. If your string has a strongly repeatitive pattern, even regex are not absolutely required:

```
ch = 'blah....ipAddress=173.110.208.118&deviceId'


print ch.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]

print ch.split('=')[1][0:15]

print ch[-34:].strip('ipAddress=&deviceId')
```

result

```
173.110.208.118
173.110.208.118
173.110.208.118
```